# how do i change the format in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have a table like this

| grade | name | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | 25 |
| 1 | abc | 30 |
| 1 | abc | 35 |
| 2 | xyz | 40 |
| 2 | xyz | 45 |
| 2 | xyz | 50 |
| 3 | mno | 55 |
| 3 | mno | 60 |
| 3 | mno | 65 |

and I want a table like this

| grade | abc | xyz | mno |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 25 | 40 | 55 |
| 2 | 30 | 45 | 60 |
| 3 | 35 | 50 | 65 |

i tried to transpose the dataframe in pandas but didnt work..

how can i convert this..?

Comment: You can't obtain your output with your input... because you have 3 instances of (1, abc), (2, xyz) and (3, mno)

Comment: You do no do transpose as you change the relation between grade, name and price.

Answer (score 1):

To get your output, your input should be:

```
>>> df
   grade name  price   # your grade column
0      1  abc     25   # 1
1      2  abc     30   # 1
2      3  abc     35   # 1
3      1  mno     55   # 2
4      2  mno     60   # 2
5      3  mno     65   # 2
6      1  xyz     40   # 3
7      2  xyz     45   # 3
8      3  xyz     50   # 3
```

If you have the input above, you can use `pivot`:

```
>>> df.pivot('grade', 'name', 'price').reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)
   grade  abc  mno  xyz
0      1   25   55   40
1      2   30   60   45
2      3   35   65   50
```